# Change tag [valueinjecter] to [valueinjector]

Tags: support, status-declined, retag-request

The [valueinjecter](/questions/tagged/valueinjecter) tag may be incorrectly spelled on StackOverflow. I found [valueinjector](/questions/tagged/valueinjector) (with `-or`) to be the correct spelling.

Can someone correct the spelling?

**Update**

Although I found the product name spelled both ways, the correct spelling is, indeed [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/).

Comment: omg :D so much trouble cuz I named it wit er :D

Comment: @Omu: I know, right ...mad bad!  :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**...Not so fast!**

Yes, the proper English phrase would be "value injector". But it appears that there is a fairly popular code library for ASP.NET applications that goes by the name [Value Injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/).

Chances are, questions tagged [valueinjecter](/questions/tagged/valueinjecter) refer to that library.

There might be some questions that *aren't* about that library that got that tag applied to them accidentally, but those questions need to be manually retagged.

Comment: There are only 53 questions, I skimmed them all and the previews indicate that they are all about the popular library.   Also, beat you by 5 seconds.  FGITW! :)

Comment: I found I am wrong...I should be able to down-vote my own question???  ha hah

Answer (score 8):

Don't do this.

You are correct that `-or` is the correct spelling for most uses of the word ['injector'](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/injector) (as used in [fuel injectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_injector) [etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injector)).

However, [valueinjecter](/questions/tagged/valueinjecter) is the correct spelling of the name of the program referenced in these questions.  It's spelled that way in their URL: [http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) and on their website:

> [image]

The author, [o](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/o), knows that this is not the correct spelling.  However, it's too late to change now and they don't want to change it as reported in the response to [this closed bug report](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/workitem/7372#CommentContainer1).

Therefore, the spelling should not be changed in the tag.

Comment: Yes, I am wrong about this. :)